# How to populate ListCollectionView from multiple sources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm autogenerating columns based on a set. After that, I'm adding one of my own, manually, like this.

```
private void OnAutoGeneratedColumns(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
  DataGridColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn { ... };
  DataGrid grid = sender.Get<DataGrid>();
  grid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

It adds the column and I can see the header being set according to the code. However, I'm not sure how to add any data to it. Checking the list of properties didn't offer me a clue. How should one do that?

The additional column is to be rendered based on the information from the same line in the grid (e.g. if the autogenerated columns are *FirstName* and *LastName*, the manually added one would be *FullName* and consist of the concatenation of them).

One approach I can think of is to inherit the class that is being used to autogenerate the columns, extend it with a new property and put it in the constructor of my view model like so. Then I could bind to the latter instead of the former.

```
BasicView = new ListCollectionView(basicThings);
ExtendedView = new ListCollectionView(extendedThings);

class ExtendedThing : BasicThing
{
  public String FullName { get { return FirstName + LastName; } }
}
```

But that seems like a rather major intrusion into the code, which makes me suspect I'm heading in the wrong direction...

Comment: Do you use MVVM? Model provides data (first name and last name), ViewModel adds full name column and populate data and then View simply displays it.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, I'm using MVVM. And yes, the information you provided is 100% correct. However, I'm not sure how it addresses the question. I want to manipulate the view **while assigning** the source set. But the items' set to be displayed, comes from multiple sources and I'm not certain what's the best way to handle it.

Comment: ViewModel should provide all data needed for the View. I don't understand where are multiple sources (multiple Models?). I think you are trying to modify View, but it would be much easier to modify ViewModel. You are not sure how to add data to autogenerated column. Simply. It should already be there (ViewModel populates it, it can be a simple property which return first name + last name, no additional memory consumption). It's just not displayed yet, unless you add new column and bind to `FullName` and then it is automagically *added*.

Comment: @Sinatr Ah, I see where the confusion comes from. It's not like that at all in my case. In my view model I have an array that is presented in a data grid (autogenerated columns). But in that data grid, I want an addition column (*FullName*). I'm adding the custom column to the grid **after** the generation process is firing the event. But I'm not sure how to populate it (although I have a property in my view model holding the data). The only approach I've found this far is to add the property to the array that's displayed in the data grid. But it feels like an extensive intrusion for it.